# Dynamics CRM 2011 document management - disable alert on folder existence

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011, document-management

I have successfully setup CRM and SharePoint for document management. But when there is already an folder in sharepoint 2010 library which CRM would like to create, it asks if I want to hook this entity with this folder.

My question is: is it possible to disable this question and automatically hook existing folder with current entity?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the document location entity record in CRM prior to SharePoint process it won't ask the question. You need to find a business process when to create the document location entity record.